# Удаление записей из множества таблиц MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Имеется около 50-ти идентичных по структуре таблиц. Возникла необходимость удаления записей из всех этих таблиц, где дата создания записей более одного года.

**Вот пример запроса на удаление:**

```
DELETE FROM `table1` WHERE (`DelDate` <= '".$Date."')";
```

**Как лучше организовать запрос на удаление из всех 50-ти таблиц? Спасибо.**

Comment: запрос на удаление работает с одной таблицей. Единственная организация тут - сложить имена таблиц в массив и в цикле выполнить запросы. хорошо бы при этом иметь индексы по полю фильтрации, если таблицы мало-мальски большие.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду такой порядок: 1. Выбираем из всех таблиц записи для удаления. 2. Создаём массив из таблиц. 3. В цикле удаляем выбранные записи.

Comment: а так не вариант? ``DELETE FROM table1, table2, table3...
WHERE table1.DelDate= date
AND table2.Deldate = date....;``

Comment: как то так видимо `$tables = ['t1', 't2']; foreach ($tables as $t){ $db->exec("delete from {$t} where ...") }`

Answer (score 0):

Использовать каскадное удаление
https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я так понимаю, мне нужно вносить изменения в базу? Может есть еще какие-либо варианты?

Comment: Да, нужно создать внешний ключ на таблицы. Еще вариант использовать триггер.

Comment: с чего в взяли что таблицы связаны вообще как-то логически?

Comment: Если не связаны, тогда только триггер вешать

Comment: Таблицы не связаны.

Comment: Таблицы не связаны. Если использовать триггер, мне нужно что-то изменять в базе? Если можно, дайте пример триггера в моем случае, так как не совсем понятно что делать с этим колличеством таблиц.